# symfony - Given object is not an instance of the class this property was declared in

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have tried to add 'Exam Categories' into my form:

```
class ExamType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            // ...
            ->add('categories', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => ExamCategory::class,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => false,
                'label' => 'Kategoria',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                        ->orderBy('c.name');
                },
            ])
            // ...
        ;
    }
}
```

Here is ExamCategory entity:

```
class ExamCategory
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Exam", mappedBy="categories")
     */
    private $exams;

    // ...

    /**
     * @return Collection|Exam[]
     */
    public function getExams(): Collection
    {
        return $this->exams;
    }

    // ...
}
```

and the base Exam entity:

```
class Exam
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\ExamCategory", inversedBy="exams")
     */
    private $categories;

    // ...

    /**
     * @return Collection|ExamCategory[]
     */
    public function getCategories(): Collection
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    // ...
}
```

I have tried to clear cache, meta-data from Doctrine but it was not help.
When I have removed this field, form renders without problems (namespace is correct, I don't have find any typo).

Comment: And which exactly is the problem?

Comment: @iiirxs I'm getting error like in subject: `Given object is not an instance of the class this property was declared in`

Comment: You should also paste the code where the form is created.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Please dont put such infos about error messages into comments. Always update the question instead.